# menu bar gone in visual studio code macos

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm on a macbook just messing around with a project I had when I suddenly did something and now my menu bar and my explorer on the left side of the screen is gone:

[image: picture of my vsc]

This is a picture from google to better demonstrate what I'm looking for:

[image: picture of what i want back]

I tried to find the layout file and then just delete it making the thing reset it self but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Your 2nd picture is referring to the "side bar", not the "menu bar": https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface

Answer (score 0):

um i actually found the file now so its all good:) if anyone in the future have the same problem just go to "~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/" (macos) and delete the settings.json and then just restart the visual studio code app and its all good